# What is the default Max Connection Duration time in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, websocket, aws-application-load-balancer

We have a Websocket application running on Kubernetes which we want to expose via AWS LoadBalancer.

During our release process, traffic will be migrated to new pod, and connections will be drained from the old pod.

We have seen some clients connected to the old pod more than 30 minutes as well.

Before we go for more use cases in production environment, we want to know what is the max connection duration time in ALB. What will happen to connections to the old pod if the connection persists for more than 1 hour.

Comment: These are the Loadbalancer Attributes 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#load-balancer-attributes

Answer (score 0):

As per AWS response to following there is no configurable attributes for max connection duration

[AWS response](https://repost.aws/questions/QU4q9Qoz8NQ8C33bc3PF150w/does-the-aws-alb-have-a-max-connection-timeout-available)

This has Loadbalancer configurable attributes ,again there is no configurable attribute for max connection duration
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#load-balancer-attributes

Comment: you better quote the important part of those resources, than just adding a link.

Comment: ok, edited the above response